# How can I pass the unselected radio button value in a hidden field in laravel 4?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4, radio-button

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'game/winner', 'class' => 'form game play')) }}
<ul>
<?php foreach($players as $player) : ?>
<li>
    <div class="radio radio-primary">
        <label>
            {{ Form::radio('player', $player->id, false, ['class' => 'radio']) }}
            <span class="circle"></span>
            <span class="check"></span>
            <?php echo $player->firstname; ?>
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<li>
    {{ Form::submit('End Game', array('class' => 'btn btn-success submit')) }}
</li>
</ul>{{ Form::close() }}
```

I loop through players and produce radio buttons, a maximum of two, then the user selects a winner and submits the form. How can I pass the unselected value also so I can use that data in the view this form directs too?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly - you already have the list of radio buttons - since each radio button represents a `$player`.

So just get the route `game/winner` to pull the list of `$players` again on the server side, and simply pass it the selected `$player` that was selected by the user.